# How to store a private key in Github and VSTS Continuous Integration?

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops

I have a private API key that I am using in my public Github project. I would like to keep this key private. Currently, I am doing this using an Environment Variable.

The problem I'm running into is that this project is also integrated into VSTS Continuous Integration environment. So when my code runs there, the key is not available since it's only on my local machine.

I've tried using Azure Key Vault as recommended by Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/vs-secure-secret-appsettings). But that code didn't work for me. I downloaded the Nuget package that they recomended. However, when I tried to use this code the compiler had no idea what IWebHost or Startup is:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, builder) =>
        {
            var keyVaultEndpoint = GetKeyVaultEndpoint();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyVaultEndpoint))
            {
                var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
                var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
                    new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
                        azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
                        builder.AddAzureKeyVault(
                        keyVaultEndpoint, keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
                    }
                })
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this?

Comment: KeyVault is the correct answer. What do you mean when you say "didn't work"? Provide **precise** details.

Comment: I updated the question with what didn't work

Comment: @NikolayAdvolodkin After using Azure key vault to store your ptivate key, you need to use Azure Key Vault task (learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/deploy/…) to download the private key firstly, and then use it in your VSTS build.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT can you supply that URL please, this one returns 404 learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/deploy/ . Where will I download the key, locally? Will that fix the compiler issues related to the code that I supplied above?

Comment: @NikolayAdvolodkin Sorry for it. The url should be https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-key-vault?view=vsts. And I also add the details in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Azure Key Vault task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-key-vault?view=vsts)** to download the private keys to the agent machine firstly, and then use key by related variable in VSTS build.

Assume there has an priavte key `mykey` in Azure key vault, after Azure Key Vault task, you can use the variable `$(mykey)` to get the key value.

Comment: Download the key? It doesn't seem like I have control of the agent as it seems to be provided by VSTS, do I? If that is the case, then couldn't I just add an Environment Variable on the agent and then my problem will be solved? The reason I even started looking at Azure Key Vault was because I thought I have no control of what goes on inside of the agent...

Comment: The download action is provided by Azure Key Vault task  not agent itself. And if you are using Hosted agent, it does can not be controlled. Besides, you can also refer add secrete variable in your build definition directly (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/build/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch#secret-variables), if it meets your requirement.